# iOS uilabel stay on screen when scrolling

Tags: ios, scroll, position, uilabel, alert

In my app I was giving some information like "connection error" or "image saved" when users

caused some events. Instead of using alert view, I'd like to show labels with those text

on screen for 
about 2-3 secs and disappear automatically.

Most like what Android apps would do like [this](http://imgur.com/8qns2BF).
(sorry for a link rather than post image due to low rep.)

As I did  **[superView addSubview:label]**  my label was attached on the back view and moved by scrolling.(superView = tableView)

How could I keep it at a fixed position of screen when user's scrolling it's superView?

prefer simple solution without using 3rd party...
tho any advance would be appreciated.

Comment: a quick solution would be to use a 3rd party lib like https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD

Comment: thanks for quick reply! perhaps it's the simplest way using 3rd party

Comment: yeah, there are tons of those of those out there, and you don't get this behaviour out of the box in iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a label to the superview and make it hidden

```
label.hidden = YES; // write this in viewDidLoad()
```

And in event action unhide the label

```
label.hidden = NO;
```

and then set a timer so that after 2 or 3 second the label will disapear.

```
//inside event action
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

and in the selector method write code for hiding the label

```
 - (void) hideLabel
 {
  _lblClick.hidden = YES;  
 }
```

I hope this is what you want......

Comment: thanks for reply! tho the position problem is the main headache

Answer (score 0):

After you add the view to your superView , You can use the `[superView bringSubviewToFront:<#(UIView *)#>]` method. This will block some of your scrollView scrolling space, but will keep your label in the frontmost part of your view.

You can use UIView's animation to add to show and hide the label

Comment: Can you please add some code so we can see what are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the label to scrolling superView. Instead add it to parent of superView or the viewControllers primaryView(by default self.view) and use hidden property. Use autolayout to position the label for various layouts.

Comment: 'm using tableView controller, self.view seems equal to tableView